# How do I declare multiple maintainers in my Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How can I best indicate that there are multiple authors/maintainers of a docker image built using a `Dockerfile`? If I include multiple separate `MAINTAINER` commands, only the last one seems to take effect.

```
MAINTAINER Me Myself "myself@example.com"
MAINTAINER My Colleague "mycolleague@example.com"
```

Only `mycolleague` shows up in the output of `docker inspect`.

Should I use a comma delimited list in a single `MAINTAINER` line? Is wanting to list two maintainers a boondoggle and I should just armwrestle my colleague to see whose email we put in the file?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution as well. Maybe it's just okay to have multiple maintainers in one line?

Comment: Probably, yeah. If `MAINTAINER` is an arbitrary string (or series of whitespace delimited tokens) then I would imagine it fine to put multiple people on one line. I'm just not sure whether there's a common convention for it.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can only specify one `MAINTAINER` instruction in a Dockerfile.

Furthermore, `MAINTAINER` will be deprecated in the upcoming 1.13.0 release, see [deprecations](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/docs/deprecated.md#maintainer-in-dockerfile) and this [pull request](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/25466).

The recommended solution is to use [`LABEL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label)  instead, e.g.

```
LABEL authors="first author,second author"
```

Labels have a `key=value` syntax. This means you cannot assign the same label more than once and you cannot assign multiple values to a given label. But you can combine multiple values into one with a syntax of your choice as illustrated in the example..

Comment: [The current recommendation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#maintainer-deprecated) is to use `"org.opencontainers.image.authors"` as the **key**, since this a [more widely recognized metadata key](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/annotations.md). It is still freeform string **value**.

Comment: Do you know whether `org.opencontainers.image.authors` should always be the key, or should the first few parts be my own organization's reversed domain, like `com.example.image.authors`?

Comment: Good question, @amacleod. It seems that exactly `org.opencontainers.image.authors` should be used as the key, since it is specified in the OCI specs, see the referred [OCI image-spec annotations](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/annotations.md):
"The prefix `org.opencontainers` is reserved for keys defined in Open Container Initiative (OCI) specifications and MUST NOT be used by other specifications and extensions"